# Postman - Update CSV Separator in Runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Is there a way to update separator to read CSV file in Postman Runner. By Default is ",". But I would like to change it as ";".

[image]

Maybe there is a postman javascript reference that I could use in the pre-request script of my endpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no you can't.

It wouldn't work in a pre-request script as it would have already got past the point of picking up the file data.

You can access the file data using  `pm.iterationData.get()` but it uses that separator in the *comma separated value* file, to establish the variable names and the iteration values.